# Installed Nuget for Windows Community Toolkit - tried to use TabView, build error

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

To reproduce: in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, create new Blank App (Universal Windows), leave the "Select the target and minimum platform versions that your UWP application will support" at the defaults:
Target version: Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0; Build 18362)
Minimum version: Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; Build 17763)
Left it set to Debug, x86 and launched -- I can see the blank app. Check.

Installed Nuget package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI

Within MainPage.xaml I added the XML namespace: xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

and then tried to use the TabView from this toolkit thusly:

..

I am getting "Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers, .."

Why is it depending upon Parsers, and why is that not included? What's going on?

Thank you for any help,

JH

Windows 10 x64
Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.6

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might install the wrong Nuget package. As the namespace shows, it should be `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` Nuget package instead of `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI`.

I created a sample followed your step, but I just changed the Nuget Package to `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` and everything works well now.

So please change the Nuget package and have a try again.